# Open Different App's or EXE on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i hope that someone can help me figure this out, I have a requirement to open different system’s install on a pc, something like a page with a few buttons each one will open for example, excel, word, internal systems, a different URL, etc.
I know that something like this is possible with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“Process”)`, but a few of this programs had a weird path or specific to a user, I am trying to use a Web service to open this if this is even possible.

When I code the WebMethod and test it on my PC works, but if deplot it and try it form the server throws an error.

As I far as I can tell, it might think in a different solution for this, any ideas?

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            using (Process proc = Process.Start(@"Path"))
            {

            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: You will be unable to start a process on a user's computer. The computer you posted would simply start the process on the server.  It works in testing because your computer is running a virtual host.

Comment: "It throws an error", huh? Please tell us _which_ error. Otherwise, we might help you with an error you're not getting.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467004/launching-an-executable-from-a-website

Comment: Ramhound, yes, i think you are right, do you know a way (different Technology) or something that i might need to do?, probably a service install on the user pc o be able to execute this programs??