# How to run an executable from the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, asp-classic, exe

I have to run an executable on click on a link. The executable can be on the server or on the client machine and is already installed. Can I do that using html, javascript or asp?
I'll use this on a touchscreen monitor with the browser in fullscreen mode. From the page the user can open some exe.

Comment: If you're running it on the server then it depends on the executable. For example every time you view a PHP or a Perl page hosted on IIS you run an .exe file.  Some executables can only be run if you have desktop access

Comment: There are multiple ways to start an application on the server but it won't show on the client (but you can get a response after the app terminated). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you have full access to the machine, you can made some registry entries to make custom hyperlinks protocols, like Skype and other apps does. This way works with all browsers.

You can get more info [here](http://www.openwinforms.com/run_exe_from_javascript.html)

Other ways [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815982/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-to-a-local-executable) and [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467004/launching-an-executable-from-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

1. All client machine has to install this executable in the same location
2. Only works for IE
   If this is achievable, you can modify below code to specify your exe path.

   Application Executer
       
       
           function RunFile() {
           WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
           WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
           }

Comment: The function has to be called only on a machine so I can prepar it how I want. Is there a method to use the same operation with Google Chrome?

Comment: You can if you add the MIME type to the registry and bind the executable with open method.